# I have two versions of PHP installed; how do I clean it up / control what references which?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php, imagemagick

Running CentOS + Apache + PHP + MySQL

running `yum list installed *php*` gives me this:

```
newrelic-php5-common.noarch                                         4.23.4.113-1                                            @newrelic      
php.x86_64                                                          5.3.3-46.el6_6                                          @updates       
php-cli.x86_64                                                      5.3.3-46.el6_6                                          @updates       
php-common.x86_64                                                   5.3.3-46.el6_6                                          @updates       
php-devel.x86_64                                                    5.3.3-46.el6_6                                          @updates       
php-gd.x86_64                                                       5.3.3-46.el6_6                                          @updates       
php-mysql.x86_64                                                    5.3.3-46.el6_6                                          @updates       
php-pdo.x86_64                                                      5.3.3-46.el6_6                                          @updates       
php-pear.noarch                                                     1:1.9.4-4.el6                                           @base          
php-pecl-apcu.x86_64                                                4.0.4-1.el6                                             @epel          
php-pecl-zendopcache.x86_64                                         7.0.3-1.el6                                             @epel          
php54.x86_64                                                        2.0-1.el6                                               @centos-sclo-rh
php54-php.x86_64                                                    5.4.40-4.el6                                            @centos-sclo-rh
php54-php-cli.x86_64                                                5.4.40-4.el6                                            @centos-sclo-rh
php54-php-common.x86_64                                             5.4.40-4.el6                                            @centos-sclo-rh
php54-php-gd.x86_64                                                 5.4.40-4.el6                                            @centos-sclo-rh
php54-php-mbstring.x86_64                                           5.4.40-4.el6                                            @centos-sclo-rh
php54-php-mysqlnd.x86_64                                            5.4.40-4.el6                                            @centos-sclo-rh
php54-php-pdo.x86_64                                                5.4.40-4.el6                                            @centos-sclo-rh
php54-php-process.x86_64                                            5.4.40-4.el6                                            @centos-sclo-rh
php54-php-xml.x86_64                                                5.4.40-4.el6                                            @centos-sclo-rh
php54-runtime.x86_64                                                2.0-1.el6                                               installed
```

running `php -v` gives me this:

```
PHP 5.4.40 (cli) (built: Aug 30 2016 13:52:21)
```

running `pecl install imagick` gives me this:

```
pecl/imagick requires PHP (version >= 5.4.0), installed version is 5.3.3
```

The context is that I'm running a php script through apache that uses Imagick; it worked until I upgraded PHP (from 5.3.3 to 5.4.4), where it tells me `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Imagick' not found in blah/blah/blah` .

So, I would like to get rid of php 5.3.3, but would also like to understand the ridiculous mess of wiring of everything to everything else that's going on.

So, more precisely: **What do I need to do to get imagick installed and used by apache + php 5.4.4?**

bonus questions:

- I noticed the php 5.4 binaries (?) all have the prefix php54, yet the 5.3 versions are just 'php'. Am I supposed to delete the old 'php' version and then alias all the php54 stuff to just php?
- Is there some universal 'php' construct that declares the system wide "I'm the default php, use me"?
- Does `pear` and `pecl` need to be reinstalled through php 5.4?

Comment: You installed these packages? Where did they come from?

Comment: Is this Cento 6? If so, remove php.x86_64 - which is 5.3.3. That will leave 5.4.40. Yum is seeing that 5.3 is installed and that is causing a dependency problem. As an aside, 5.3 and 5.4 are both EOL.